# Can we use combiner to replace reduce in Mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can we use combiner to replace reduce in Mapreduce job? If not, what can we use to replace reducer in mapreduce job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no.

A combiner is only called when there is at least one reducer called.

When there is no reducer, the job stops at the map phase, omitting the local sorting on the outputs of the map tasks. This sorting is also required by the combiners (they are actually local reducers). So, no reducers => no combiners.

However, you can sometimes simulate the operation of a combiner, if you use in-mapper aggregation. For example, you could store the results of wordcount from the mapper in a local data structure, summing up and emitting the local frequency of each word when each mapper ends, i.e., when it calls the `cleanup()` method. At the end of this job, you can end up having duplicate words with different counts, originating from different input splits, but this is as close as you can get to the functionality of a reducer, without using a reducer.